# CrashLoopBackOff: Docker image not running on Kubernates ? (ImagePullBackOff)

Tags: java, maven, docker, kubernetes

- I have a REST API application with the following maven and docker file.
- I am using Jdk 8, latest Docker and Kubernates, latest minicubi , and work on latest Mac OS

I was able to create the docker image without any problem as well as deploy it on Kubernate. However here the status when I run `kubectl get pods`

```
NAME                                     READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE employee-2271331337-vj6v2             0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   29         2h office365-email-3450521264-nrtkr      0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          5h our-node-2-3162948349-lelwt 1/1       Running            0          23h
```

Then I run the following code to see the log `kubectl logs e-office365-2271331337-vj6v2 -p`and found the following log:

> lugin-group-id>:[:]:.
>   Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize,
>   generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources,
>   process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources,
>   process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources,
>   test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package,
>   pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify,
>   install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site,
>   post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1] [ERROR]

**DockerFile:**

```
# Dockerfile

FROM  phusion/baseimage:0.9.17


RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -q python-software-properties software-properties-common

ENV JAVA_VER 8
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle


ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.3.9


ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven

RUN echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo 'deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C2518248EEA14886 && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java${JAVA_VER}-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends oracle-java${JAVA_VER}-installer oracle-java${JAVA_VER}-set-default && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk${JAVA_VER}-installer


RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven \
  && curl -fsSL http://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz \
    | tar -xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

RUN update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle

RUN echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle" >> ~/.bashrc

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

VOLUME /root/.m2

CMD ["mvn"]
```

**Maven:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <properties>
        <dropwizard.version>1.0.0</dropwizard.version>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.emp</groupId>
    <artifactId>empv1</artifactId>
    <version>EMP-208-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>config.EmailUtilApplication</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.34</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
                <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smoketurner</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>



</project>
```

I appericiate your help to make sure the images runs on kubernates.

Comment: That looks like an application error from within your container itself. You could try to [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) your container to ensure that it is setup correctly.

Comment: Can you please include the log where you see `ImagePullBackOff`? That would not usually be caused by an application issue, so it appears you have two separate issues here.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan You are right. There is a problem with docker. So some issues with mvn. I'll try to solve that first. ChaosAffe I see ImagePullBackOff in the status of each images not in a log file.

Comment: @WowBow : Could you please post your pods definition ?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your Dockerfile, you twice define CMD, but the last one is just "mvn" without any lifecyle information. That's why you get the feedback from maven and the container terminates:

```
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

VOLUME /root/.m2

CMD ["mvn"]
```